# "bad request" when making an Outlook REST API POST request to send mail with a hyperlink included

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am trying to use the Outlook REST API to send a message on behalf of the user. 
The request works fine with html or text until I try to include a link `<a href=\"google.com\">here</a>` in the html message.

If I remove the link from the message or even replace it with a different piece of html code such as `<b>google.com</b>`, then it works fine, but with the link it responds with `Bad Request`

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, the \ is before the " because my program is in java and \" is the escape key for "

Answer (score 0):

figured out the problem. For some reason removing the "" around the link fixed it. :)